# Ruby - .each Method - coding is not executing

Tags: ruby, visual-studio-code

I am new to coding and am learning visual studio code and am following along "Learn Visual Studio Code Udemy course. 
In this video, the instructor can add the settings into a file called User Settings. 
1) How do I create this setting? 
2) I have tried the following steps. I can now see Workspace in the VScode. but I do not have file to add Fira code. 
Thank you very much!

1. Download the Fira Code font from https://github.com/tonsky/FiraCode
2. Then navigate to FiraCode-master\distr\ttf
3. Double click on each .ttf file
4. Then go to VS Code > Setting (Ctrl,) > Text Editor > Font >

Font Family : 'Fira Code', monospace

Font Ligatures : Enable[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CK0NJ.jpg)

Another problem is Ruby .each method. The following code should give output of 5, 15, etc. But I am not getting it. Thank you very much in advance!

```
fives = [5,10,15,20,25,30,35,40]
odds =[]
fives.each do |num|
    odds = []
    if num.odd?
        odds << num
    end  
end
```

Comment: This should be 2 separate questions.  The first part of your question is too broad and has nothing to do with actual code, while the ruby part of your question sounds like an afterthought. Please see https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Can I ask you a question? (&:odd) –  & is AND and :is symbol and odd is what I want. Am I right?

Comment: not really.  `array.select(&:odd?)` is shorthand way of writing `array.select{|i| i.odd?}`.  So here `&` means iterate over each item in the array and call `:odd?` on each item.

Answer (score 1):

For the ruby part of your question, you are incorrectly assigning two empty array variables called `odd` with the same name both outside and inside your `.each` loop so that won't work. In fact you need neither of them, but you also have not made clear what you mean by "give output of".  If you mean to print it to the screen than you can use the `puts` or `print` methods.

```
fives = [5,10,15,20,25,30,35,40]
fives.each do |num|
  puts num if num.odd?
end
```

If you want to print output the array as a string with comma separated on a single line you can do:

```
fives = [5,10,15,20,25,30,35,40]
puts fives.select(&:odd?).join(',')
```

Comment: Thank you!!!!!!!!!!! It works like a charm. I can print the output in a single line. :)

Answer (score 1):

```
fives = [5,10,15,20,25,30,35,40]
odds =[]
fives.each do |num|
    odds = []  # <== REMOVE THIS
    if num.odd?
        odds << num
    end  
end
```

Just remove the second `odds = []` , which gives you an empty array every loop.

Answer (score 1):

What you want is something like this:

```rb
fives = (5..40).step(5)
odds = fives.select(&:odd?)
puts odds
```

Comment: Thanks for your explanation :)  step(5) and (&:odd?) are new things I learn!

Answer (score 0):

Your code will add 5,15, etc. to your array `odds`, but it does not contain any code to print its contents.

You can use something like this at the end of your code to print the odd multiples of five.

```
odds.each do |odd|
   puts odd
end
```